# Asymptotics of 0-1 classification loss

Tags: classification, linear-model, asymptotics, loss-functions

I am interested in training a simple binary linear classifier.  That is, I will find a vector of weights $\bf w$ such that I can predict the class of new example by the sign of

$f(x) = w^T x$.

I will find the weights in the standard way, by minimizing the empirical risk of some loss function

$\sum_i L(w^T x^{(i)}, y^(i))$

Many different loss functions have been suggested to solve this problem, such as the hinge loss

$L(w^T x, y) = \max(0,1-y\ w^T x)$,

the "logistic" loss

$L(w^T x, y) = \log(1 + \exp(-y\ w^T x))$,

and the "0-1" loss

$L(w^T x, y) = I(y = \text{sign}( w^T x))$.

The 0-1 loss is rarely used in practice due to non-convexity.  However, suppose that we were able to minimize it.  If the data is "noisy" or non-separable, we can expect the 0-1 loss to outperform the others (in terms of classification rate) given infinite data, since 
it is robust to outliers.  My question is this: does the 0-1 loss have a convergence *rate* equal to the others?  (Edit: Here by convergence rate, I mean in the traditional statistical sense of the expected squared difference between the recovered weights and the true weights, though I would be interested in other notions of convergence as well.)

I would be interested in an answer in any setting, but the simplest might be to assume that the data *is* in fact separable.  My intuition tells me that here the logistic or hinge loss will outperform the 0-1 loss, but I can't quantify this.

Of course, if there were a result for a different classifier than linear, that would be of interest as well.

Comment: If the data are separable, does not any solution obtained by Rosenblatt's perceptron algorithm give zero training error under 0-1 loss? Similarly, logistic regression will achieve perfect classification in this case.

Comment: I think so.  But here, I am interested in the convergence rate.  So, though various loss functions might give zero training error, what should we expect with *test* error?

Comment: I think you should edit your question and clarify what you mean by *convergence rate*, then. Your usage appears a bit nonstandard to me, so I think it might help others as well if you spell that part out explicitly.

Comment: OK, I updated which hopefully clarifies.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the updates, but note that $w$ is not even necessarily identifiable (without further assumptions) in the separable case, so $\mathbb E \|\hat{W} - w\|^2$ does not make sense. Indeed, in this case, $w$ will only be identifiable if the margin is zero. Of course, one might argue that such an example is pathological and, for most practical purposes, it probably is. :)

Comment: Hmmm...  I'm happy to assume whatever regularity conditions needed to make the weight vector identifiable.  Alternatively, I suppose what I *really* want is to show that $||{\hat f}-f||$ goes to zero where ${\hat f}(x)={\hat w}^T x$ and $f(x)=w^T x$ and $||\cdot||$ is some functional norm.  But I'll take what (if anything) I can get!